# mkdir: cannot create directory Permission denied

Tags: linux, bash

Estoy intentando crear una nueva carpeta en home pero me aparece "permision denied".

```
pipeservicios@SERVIDOR:/mnt/c/Users/Felipe$ cd /home
pipeservicios@SERVIDOR:/home$ ls
noroot  pipeservicios
pipeservicios@SERVIDOR:/home$ mkdir prueba
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘prueba’: Permission denied
pipeservicios@SERVIDOR:/home$
```

Comment: sudo mkdir prueba

Answer (score 2):

Eso significa que tu usuario no tiene permisos de escritura sobre el directorio `/home`.

Lo que yo recomendaría es que **no crearas tu carpeta en** `/home`, ya que esa carpeta está dedicada para guardar el workspace de cada usuario en el sistema.

En lugar de intentar hacer eso, mejor utiliza la carpeta `/tmp` y dentro crea todo lo que quieras, siempre y cuando quieras que sea temporal, ya que suelen existir programas que borran automáticamente lo que esté dentro de `/tmp`.

Las carpetas dentro de `/home` sólo tienen sentido si están asociadas a algún usuario del sistema.

De todas maneras lo puedes crear utilizando, `sudo mkdir /home/prueba`

O también creando un usuario y asignando esa carpeta como su workspace:

```
$ sudo useradd -md /home/prueba prueba
$ ls /home
prueba
```

Answer (score 0):

Este es un problema de permiso, generalmente cuando no tiene el permiso adecuado
derechos/acceso para realizar alguna operación en una ubicación específica o con algunos archivos. Aquí no tiene permiso para crear una carpeta en el directorio de inicio. Se puede resolver si usa la  `Sudo mkdir prueba` como se sugiere en el comentario de David (obviamente, también necesita permiso aquí).

Este comando solicita la contraseña para iniciar sesión como superusuario. Si no tiene la contraseña, puede preguntarle al administrador o pedirle que lo agregue como nuevo usuario.

Comment: ¡El lenguaje oficial del sitio es el español! Traduce tu respuesta.